# The Torah laws are not for revenge - who said the opposite?

Tags: rambam, revenge-nekama

> ואסור להתמהמה בחילול שבת לחולה שיש בו סכנה שנאמר  אשר
>   יעשה אותם האדם וחי בהם ולא שימות בהם, **הא למדת שאין משפטי התורה נקמה
>   בעולם** אלא רחמים וחסד ושלום בעולם, ואלו המינים שאומרים שזה חילול שבת
>   ואסור עליהן הכתוב אומר וגם אני נתתי להם חוקים לא טובים ומשפטים לא יחיו
>   בהם." (Rambam, Shabat, chapter 2, paragraph 3)

It seems that Rambam means to someone who claimed that the laws of the bible are for revenge. Assuming that's correct, then I'm asking who said that Torah laws are revenge in the world? (In the past I was told that Christians said something like that. Is it true?)

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. Please clarify exactly what you mean by 'revenge in the world'.

Comment: Where do you see that anyone said that Torah laws are for vengeance? The only quote I see here is that some heretics said that violating shabbat to save a life is forbidden.

Comment: The Gnosticism.

Comment: See in the third part of More Nevuchim

Comment: @JoelK I edited the post. and see also here: https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=_b8DQOQ7IOQC&pg=PA483&dq=%22%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94+%D7%A0%D7%A7%D7%9E%D7%94+%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjN3cfIz7jgAhVuw4sKHUZ1DgcQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%A0%D7%A7%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D%22&f=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the current called [Gnosticism](https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%92%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A1)

See More nevuchim third part,  [Chapter 12].

He says that the hardness of life is for those philosophers a consequence that g-d created world and humankind to take a revenge on them. But the truth is that most sufferences occuring to a man are consequence of his lack of whatchfulness.

> הרבה פעמים יעלה בלב ההמון שהרעות בעולם יהיו יותר מן הטובות, עד שבהרבה מחידות רוב האומות ובשיריהם יכללו זה הענין, ויאמרו כי מן הפלא שימצא בזמן דבר טוב אמנם רעותיו רבות ומתמידות. ואין זה הטעות אצל ההמון לבד, רק עם מי שיחשוב שהוא חכם גם כן, ולאלראזי ספר מפורסם קראהו ספר אלהות כלל בו משגעונותיו וסכלויותיו הרבה, ומכללם ענין בדאו והוא שהרע במציאות יותר מן הטוב, שאתה כשתקיש בין מנוחת האדם ועונגו בעת מנוחתו, עם מה שיקראהו מן המכאובים והחבלים הקשים והמומים וביטול האברים והמהומות והדאגות והצרות, תמצא שבמציאותו ר״ל **מציאות האדם נקמה ממנו ורעה גדולה לו**. והתחיל לאמת זה הדעת במנותו אלה הרעות אחת אחת, לחלוק על מה שיחשבו אנשי האמת מגמילות חסדי ה׳ למציאותו וטובתו המבוארת והיותו יתעלה הטוב הגמור בלא ספק. וכל מה שיבא מאתו טוב גמור. ‏

And regarding the more acurately your question I don't find a text more accurate, maybe in Chapter 32.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a set of antisemitic accusations, partly stemming from Christian teachings, that "the Jewish God is a God of vengeance and the Christian God a God of love" (taken from [here](http://incharacter.org/archives/justice/jewish-vengeance-christian-compassion-or-the-misunderstanding-that-wont-go-away/)).

I will only answer with this quote from the Rambam ([Hilchot Deot 7:7](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/910347/jewish/Deot-Chapter-Seven.htm)) which apply to both vengeance itself and the accusations you mention

> A person who takes revenge against a colleague transgresses a Torah
>   prohibition, as [the Torah in Leviticus 19:18] states: "Do not take revenge."
>
> Even though [revenge] is not punished by lashes, it is a very bad
>   trait. Instead, a person should [train himself] to rise above his
>   feelings about all worldly things, for men of understanding consider
>   all these things as vanity and emptiness which are not worth seeking
>   revenge for.

Comment: I don’t know that this answers the question. To me it sounded like the OP was asking why the Rambam would even have thought that the Torah was for revenge that he had to say this, which this doesn’t answer. Unless I completely misread the question.

Comment: The question is explicit: *In the past I was told that Christians said something like that. Is it true?*